# Gatsby - dynamically update variable within page through button/funtion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I want to create a page that shows one image and if you click on a button (or on the image) the next image is shown.
I have an array of images through a query, and I update the index in the array through a button, but the image does not change.
My code:

```
  var i = 1
  var n = data.allFile.nodes
  return (
    <div>
    <h1>{n[i].name}</h1>
    <p>{i}</p>
    <GatsbyImage image={getImage(n[i])} alt={n[i].name} />
    <button onClick={() => {i = nextImage(i); console.log(i)}}>next</button>
    </div>
  )
```

Code for function `nextImage(i)`:

```
function nextImage(i) {
  i = (i+1)%3      // %3 is done to keep i in the boundary of the array
  return i
}
```

Is there a way to update the page through a button? Or is there another way to do the whole thing in Gatsby?
I am pretty new to web-dev/gatsby so thanks for your help.
:)

I tried to put it into an higher level but the `i` value does not change within the HTML.